# Have problem after search in searcview last or middle activity in listview

Tags: android, listview, searchview, onitemclicklistener

Have problem after search in searcview last  or middle activity in listview.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    SearchView searchView;
  
    ArrayList<String> items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
        
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("st17");
        items.add("st18");
        items.add("st23");
        items.add("st29");
        items.add("st33");
        items.add("st34");
        items.add("st35");
       
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArryAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        android.R.id.text1, items);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, position, l) -> {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click -" + adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_st17.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_st18.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_st23.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_st29.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_st31.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity4);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Intent newActivity5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_st32.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity5);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Intent newActivity6 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_st33.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity6);
                    break;
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                ArrayList<String> templist = new ArrayList<>();

                for (String temp : items) {
                    if (temp.toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())) {
                        templist.add(temp);
                    }
                }
                
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, templist);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                return false;
            }
        });
        }
    }
```

I have list:

st17
st18
st23
st29
st33
st34
st35

For example, I'm looking for st33 in the search, then it shows st33 it's good, but when I click it,  opens st17.

But this shows that I click on st33 but still, after pressing, it still opens st17

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click -" + adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Help me please.